# using stream to make a collection by looking up two maps and log warn message

Tags: java, java-stream

How do i convert the below to streams, i have to look up two maps before building the Desk object and I want to throw an error if MyDesk is not setup in myDesksByName map.

```
 Map<String, MyDesk> myDesksByName = myDesks.stream()
                                            .collect(Collectors.toMap(MyDesk::desk, Function.identity()));

 Map<String, List<DeskScope>> deskScopesByName = deskScopes.stream()
                                                   .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(DeskScope::desk));

    List<Desk> desks = new ArrayList<>();
    for(String deskName: deskScopesByName.keySet()){
        List<DeskScope> deskScopesForDeskName = deskScopesByName.get(deskName);
        MyDesk myDesk  = myDesksByName.get(deskName);
        if(myDesk != null){
            for(DeskScope deskScope: deskScopesForDeskName){
                Desk deskWithScope = createDeskWithScope(myDesk, deskScope.outOfScope());
                desks.add(deskWithScope);
            }
        } else {
            LOGGER.warn("Desk {} is not setup , ignoring this desk", deskName);
        }
    }
```

Trying to convert the above to streams and also log a warning messages as above . But I get a list of stream of desk and not sure how to log the WARN message.

```
    List<Stream<Desk>> collect = deskScopesByName.keySet().stream()
            .map(deskName ->
                    deskScopesByName.get(deskName).stream()
                            .map(ds -> createDeskWithScope(myDesksByName.get(deskName), ds.outOfScope())))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Use `flatMap`. Besides that, instead of processing a `keySet()` and perform a lookup for every key, it’s better do use `entrySet()` in the first place, regardless of whether you use a loop or a Stream.

Comment: thanks for the tip, that really helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your stream results in a `List<Stream<Desk>>`, because you don't collect the inner stream to a Collection, like you did at the end of the outer stream. If you do so, you will end up with a `List<List<Desk>>`. To get rid of the nested `List` structure, you need to use `flatMap`.

If you apply this, you will end up with something like this:

```
List<Desk> collect = deskScopesByName.keySet().stream()
        .flatMap(deskName -> deskScopesByName.get(deskName).stream()
                .map(ds -> createDeskWithScope(myDesksByName.get(deskName), ds.outOfScope()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: The above does not work . deskName that is available in flatMap(...) isn't available in the next step that calls map(...). How to make the deskName available in the next step?

Comment: List<Desk> desks = deskScopesByName.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .flatMap(e -> {
                    return deskScopesByName.get(e.getKey())
                            .stream()
                            .map( ds -> createDeskWithScope(myDesksByName.get(e.getKey()), ds.outOfScope()))
                    })
                .collect(Collectors.toList());